# Unable to get token from get authtoken method in teams returning error "App resource defined in manifest and iframe origin do not match"

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Unable to get token from getauthtoken method returning error "App resource defined in manifest and iframe origin do not match"

Not understanding what this message saying  defined the same app resource  in manifest where i need too define app resource in manifest?

Comment: Hi @suma k, could you please share the manifest that you are trying and please let us know which documentation you are following.

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest for Microsoft Teams apps, you need to add all domains where your app is hosted into validDomains array, like it is shown on the screenshot below.

[image]